# How to get the reference to an item from a `HashMap` with default?

Tags: rust, reference

At some point, I needed to write a function similar to this:

```rust
fn get_item_with_default(map: &HashMap<&str, Vec<i32>>, key: &str) -> &Vec<i32> {
    map.get(key).unwrap_or(&vec![])
}
```

However, this does not compile, since the `vec![]` does not have an owner, and gets dropped instantly.
This could be solved by using the function inline like this:

```rust
let default = vec![];
let item = map.get(key).unwrap_or(&default);
```

However, this looks very ugly. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

You can return a slice, since it is possible to create a `&'static` slice:

```rust
fn get_item_with_default<'a>(map: &'a HashMap<&str, Vec<i32>>, key: &str) -> &'a [i32] {
    match map.get(key) {
        Some(v) => &**v,
        None => &[],
    }
}
```

Alternatively, create a `static` `Vec` and refer to it:

```rust
fn get_item_with_default<'a>(map: &'a HashMap<&str, Vec<i32>>, key: &str) -> &'a Vec<i32> {
    static EMPTY: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
    map.get(key).unwrap_or(&EMPTY)
}
```

Comment: Third alternative, take a `default: &Vec<i32>`, though it's probably just as bad as the inline version.

Comment: In the first case you can also use `Vec::as_slice` instead of the deref play, and that means you can still use higher-order helpers e.g `map.get(key).map_or(&[], Vec::as_slice)`. Alternatively, `map.get(key).map(Vec::as_slice).unwrap_or_default()`. Depending on context, the `map` would even be an `as_deref` if the compiler manages to infer the correct thing.

Comment: Although I don't think the helper makes much sense in the first place, it's really just duplicating the builtin API, it's not like it's that much shorter, or more convenient.